# R-complement of a list

Tags: r

I have a data frame(df) where column names are:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
```

I have a `list(list1)` of data frames which consists of column subset of df:

```
list1[1]:

    col1 col2


list1[2]:

    col2 col4
```

I want to create a list (list2) which is complement of list1.

Desired output is :

```
list2[1]

    col3  col4

list2[2]

    col1  col3
```

Namely each data frame in list2 is complement of list1 with respect to df.

How can I do that using R? I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `setdiff` to get the column names of 'df' that are not present in the 'list1' elements, and use that to `subset` the 'df'

```
list2 <- lapply(list1, function(x) df[setdiff(colnames(df), colnames(x))])

 lapply(list2, names)
 #[[1]]
 #[1] "col3" "col4"

 #[[2]]
 #[1] "col1" "col3"
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:20, 5*4, replace=TRUE),
      ncol=4, dimnames=list(NULL, paste0('col', 1:4))) )
list1 <- list(df[1:2], df[c(2,4)])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list2 <- lapply(list1, function(x) df[,!(names(df) %in% names(x))] )
```